# MobaXterm - reset terminal screen

Tags: terminal, reset, xterm, mobaxterm

I need to Reset my MobaXterm screen after some time working, however 'clear' and 'reset' commands wont work as if I was on a linux server.

Anyone have some tip?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click MobaXterm screen > Click Clear Scrollback

Note: Your MobaXterm may be set to paste on Right-Click; in this case use Ctrl+Right-Click.

Comment: This does not work in case you have mapped right click to paste. At this time I have not been able to find any shortcut or menu item to take care of this.

Comment: Does MobaXterm have a keyboard shortcut for this? I check in settings and didn't find one, and would really appreciate one.

Comment: @jhash see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218903/2604813 on this page (ctrl/shift right click)

Comment: Thank you Carlos and @marcus, both are correct, depending on the config you have! So Marcus answer is a bit more correct, since it covers all configurations you have! ctrl+shift+rightclick is a good one!

Answer (score 9):

When 'Paste using right-click' is checked, you still can use Ctrl/Shift + Right Click to pop up the contextual menu.

Answer (score 3):

To reset your MobaXterm screen, use:

1. Right click on selected MobaXterm screen > Clear Scrollback (as describe above)
2. Or, if the prompt is available, launch the command 'cls'
3. Or, in all cases (prompt available or not), press `CTRL`+`L` keyboard keys

Comment: +1 for the `cls`.  `CTRL-L ` does not erase the scrollback, just clears it from the screen (but still scrollable back)

Answer (score 3):

Mobaterm seems to like playing around with the putty configuration - so I found that right clicking on the window -> change terminal settings

`-> features -> enable everything.`

`-> window -> disable push erased text into scrollback`

the usual clear control commands

`function clear() {
    printf '\033[2J'  # clear
    printf '\033[H'   # home
}`

will now clear the screen and clear the scrollback

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the terminal window in MobaXterm.
2. In the popup menu, click `Change terminal settings...`
3. In the tree, click `Terminal` > `Features`
4. Uncheck `Disable remote-controlled clearing of scrollback`
5. In the tree, click `Window`
6. Uncheck `Reset scrollback on display activity`
7. Click the `Apply` button

You can now type `clear` and have the window clear and remove the scrollback.